# How to combine path with WebRootPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to upload some files to server using my app and I need to deliver a full path of the folder where I want to save files.
I am using `Path.Combine` method with `webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` additional folders path from appsettings.json and file name.
The code looks like this:

```
var pathString = configuration.GetValue<string>("UploadPaths:Pictures");
var path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, pathString, picture.Name);
```

And the problem is that the `webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` is just ommited in the `path` variable (path looks like pathString + picture.Name).

Any idea how to get proper path?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Asp.net core 3  then use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead of `IHostingEnvironment`.
Inject IWebHostEnvironment as a dependency into the dependent class.https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment= webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\n" + _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
    }
}
```

> When Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting was introduced in 2.1 some types
>   like IHostingEnvironment and IApplicationLifetime were copied from
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting. Some 3.0 changes cause apps to include
>   both the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
>   namespaces. Any use of those duplicate types causes an "ambiguous
>   reference" compiler error when both namespaces are referenced.
>
> This error has been addressed in 3.0.0-preview3 by marking the
>   following types obsolete and replacing them with new types. There have
>   not been any behavioral changes made for the new types, only naming.
>
> ```
> Obsolete types (warning):
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.EnvironmentName
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EnvironmentName
>
> New types:
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment : IHostEnvironment
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments
> ```
>
> Note the new IHostEnvironment IsDevelopment, IsProduction, etc.
>   extension methods are in the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting namespace
>   which may need to be added to your app.
>
> For 3.0 both the old and new types will be available from HostBulder's
>   and WebHostBuilder's dependency injection containers. The old types
>   will be removed in 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_) for `Path.Combine`. There are some weird things that can happen. Based on what you are describing, it seems like `pathString` coming from your configuration file has a root in it (i.e. it is not a relative path).

```
var path = Path.Combine("path1", "c:\path2", "path3");
// path is c:\path2\path3, since an argument with a root overrides any previous argument
```

Comment: I've just had the same problem. Actually even leading slash (ie. `/img/logo.png`) causes the previous paths being omitted. There could be some overload handling this imho.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, the physical paths to both the web root and the content root directories can be retrieved by injecting and querying the `IHostingEnvironment` service:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Post(Picture picture)
    {
        var pathString = configuration.GetValue<string>("UploadPaths:Pictures");
        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, pathString, picture.Name);
        return Content(path);
    }
}
```

You could take a look at [Getting the Web Root Path and the Content Root Path in ASP.NET Core](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core).